# No module named 'stable_baseline3' even when it is installed in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, stable-baselines

I am trying to set up stable baselines 3 in google colab. The document is connected to a local runtime on my pc through jupyter notebooks. On my pc i have installed stable baselines 3 using anaconda, and got the output saying essentially stable baselines 3 is installed. I have also run the cells:

```
!pip install stable-baselines3[extra]
```

```
!pip install stable-baselines3
```

and

```
!pip install stable-baselines3 --upgrade
```

Despite this, when i run the cell:

```
import stable_baseline3
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
etc...
```

I get the error on line 1 of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stable_baseline3'. I dont understand why this would be happening, does anybody know how it could be solved?

Comment: don't forget the 's'

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem

try to import stable-baselines3 first in alone cell and it should work

```
!pip install stable-baselines3
```

Comment: Weird solution, but worked for me.